# auto closing of tabs after sending auto message using pywhatkit

Tags: python, google-chrome, tabs

I want to send auto message using pywhatkit.
It is done by this code :

```
import pywhatkit

pywhatkit.sendwhatmsg("+92xxxxxxxxxx", "Hello ", 22, 28)
print("Successfully Sent!")
```

I have followed this link :
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/introduction-to-pywhatkit-module/

I just want to ask is there any way to auto-close the tab after sending an auto message?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to close the google chrome tab, you can simulate pressing `Ctrl+W` to close it.

you can use `keyboard` library - `pip install keyboard` in cmd, then:

```py
import keyboard

keyboard.press_and_release('ctrl+w')
```

Or you can use `win32`, `pyautogui` or any other library that let's you do it

Comment: Thanks. It is working. I added a keyboard.press_and_release('ctrl+w') But sometimes it is not able to close the WhatsApp tab.

Comment: I'm not sure how would it sometimes not work. but It might be the timing - maybe the tab isn't loaded so you can't close it yet or something like that, If so - add `time.sleep(1)` before the keyboard press.

Comment: Yes i added a delay of 10 second. now it's working . Thanks.

Comment: 10 seconds might be a bit much, but if it works it works.

Answer (score 1):

sendwhatmsg has another parameter that is tab_close

```
import pywhatkit

pywhatkit.sendwhatmsg("+92xxxxxxxxxx", "Hello ", 22, 28,tap_close=True)
print("Successfully Sent!")
```

Comment: Can't edit as the its just one char, this is the updated one:
import pywhatkit
pywhatkit.sendwhatmsg("+92xxxxxxxxxx", "Hello ", 22, 28,tab_close=True)
print("Successfully Sent!")

Answer (score 0):

```
import pywhatkit as pwk
import pyautogui as gui

try: 
    // 5 ARGUMENTS = PHONE_NUMBER,HOUR,MINUTE,TAB CLOSE = True or False, Close tab in secs //
    while(pwk.sendmessage("PHONE_NUM","H","M","True")
    gui.press("Enter")
except:
    print("Error")
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).